# I need to create variations like woo commerce in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an array like this ( array generated dynamically from DB)

```
$attr = array('color'=>array('red','pink','yello','white','black','light-yellow','maroon','neal'),"brand"=>array('nike','adidas','dg','puma','neaon'),"size"=>array(8,10,11,12,13,14,15));
```

And I need result like

```
red-nike-8
red-nike-9
red-nike-10
red-nike-11
red-nike-12
red-nike-13
red-nike-14
red-nike-15

red-adidas-8
red-adidas-9
red-adidas-10
red-adidas-11
red-adidas-12
red-adidas-13
red-adidas-14
red-adidas-15

red-dg-8
red-dg-9
red-dg-10
red-dg-11
red-dg-12
red-dg-13
red-dg-14
red-dg-15

red-puma-8
red-puma-9
red-puma-10
red-puma-11
red-puma-12
red-puma-13
red-puma-14
red-puma-15

red-neaon-8
red-neaon-9
red-neaon-10
red-neaon-11
red-neaon-12
red-neaon-13
red-neaon-14
red-neaon-15

pink-nike-8
pink-nike-9
pink-nike-10
pink-nike-11
pink-nike-12
pink-nike-13
pink-nike-14
pink-nike-15

pink-adidas-8
pink-adidas-9
pink-adidas-10
pink-adidas-11
pink-adidas-12
pink-adidas-13
pink-adidas-14
pink-adidas-15........
```

Below is my code, This work for static but I need to developed to create dynamic structure.

```
    $attr_color = array('red','pink','yello','white','black','light-yellow','maroon','neal');
    $attr_brand = array('nike','adidas','dg','puma','neaon');
    $attr_size = array(8,10,11,12,13,14,15);

    $array = array();

    foreach ($attr_color as $key => $value_one)
    {
        foreach ($attr_brand as $key => $value_two) 
        {
            foreach ($attr_size as $key => $value_three) 
            {
                $array[] = array($value_one,$value_two,$value_three);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: insteresting. And the code you tried is?

Comment: please add the code to the question and not as a comment

Comment: I guess you need to change one line `$array[] = $value_one.'-'.$value_two'-'.$value_three;`

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned dynamic array in initial, considering that it's a array of depth two containing multiple subarrays, like below code. You can add any other subarray in this, Like I have added others array.

```
$attr = [
           [
            'color1',
            'color2',
            'color3',
           ],
           [
            'brand1',
            'brand2',
            'brand3',
           ],
           [
            'size1',
            'size2',
            'size3',
           ],
           [
            'other1',
            'other2',
            'other3',
           ],
       ];
```

You have to loop like this to achieve the desired result.

```
function combinations($arrays, $i = 0) {
    if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
        return [];
    }
    if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
        return $arrays[$i];
    }

    // get combinations from subsequent arrays
    $tmp = combinations($arrays, $i + 1);

    $result = [];

    // concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
    foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
        foreach ($tmp as $t) {
            $result[] = is_array($t) ? 
                array_merge([$v], $t) :
                [$v, $t];
        }
    }

    $finalArray = [];
    foreach($result as $k => $val){
        $finalArray[$k] = implode("-",$val);
    }   

    return $finalArray;
}

$result = combinations($attr);
print_r($result);
```

Final result is listed below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => color1-brand1-size1-other1
    [1] => color1-brand1-size1-other2
    [2] => color1-brand1-size1-other3
    [3] => color1-brand1-size2-other1
    [4] => color1-brand1-size2-other2
    [5] => color1-brand1-size2-other3
    [6] => color1-brand1-size3-other1
    [7] => color1-brand1-size3-other2
    [8] => color1-brand1-size3-other3
    [9] => color1-brand2-size1-other1
    [10] => color1-brand2-size1-other2
    [11] => color1-brand2-size1-other3
    [12] => color1-brand2-size2-other1
    [13] => color1-brand2-size2-other2
    [14] => color1-brand2-size2-other3
    [15] => color1-brand2-size3-other1
    [16] => color1-brand2-size3-other2
    [17] => color1-brand2-size3-other3
    [18] => color1-brand3-size1-other1
    [19] => color1-brand3-size1-other2
    [20] => color1-brand3-size1-other3
    [21] => color1-brand3-size2-other1
    [22] => color1-brand3-size2-other2
    [23] => color1-brand3-size2-other3
    [24] => color1-brand3-size3-other1
    [25] => color1-brand3-size3-other2
    [26] => color1-brand3-size3-other3
    [27] => color2-brand1-size1-other1
    [28] => color2-brand1-size1-other2
    [29] => color2-brand1-size1-other3
    [30] => color2-brand1-size2-other1
    [31] => color2-brand1-size2-other2
    [32] => color2-brand1-size2-other3
    [33] => color2-brand1-size3-other1
    [34] => color2-brand1-size3-other2
    [35] => color2-brand1-size3-other3
    [36] => color2-brand2-size1-other1
    [37] => color2-brand2-size1-other2
    [38] => color2-brand2-size1-other3
    [39] => color2-brand2-size2-other1
    [40] => color2-brand2-size2-other2
    [41] => color2-brand2-size2-other3
    [42] => color2-brand2-size3-other1
    [43] => color2-brand2-size3-other2
    [44] => color2-brand2-size3-other3
    [45] => color2-brand3-size1-other1
    [46] => color2-brand3-size1-other2
    [47] => color2-brand3-size1-other3
    [48] => color2-brand3-size2-other1
    [49] => color2-brand3-size2-other2
    [50] => color2-brand3-size2-other3
    [51] => color2-brand3-size3-other1
    [52] => color2-brand3-size3-other2
    [53] => color2-brand3-size3-other3
    [54] => color3-brand1-size1-other1
    [55] => color3-brand1-size1-other2
    [56] => color3-brand1-size1-other3
    [57] => color3-brand1-size2-other1
    [58] => color3-brand1-size2-other2
    [59] => color3-brand1-size2-other3
    [60] => color3-brand1-size3-other1
    [61] => color3-brand1-size3-other2
    [62] => color3-brand1-size3-other3
    [63] => color3-brand2-size1-other1
    [64] => color3-brand2-size1-other2
    [65] => color3-brand2-size1-other3
    [66] => color3-brand2-size2-other1
    [67] => color3-brand2-size2-other2
    [68] => color3-brand2-size2-other3
    [69] => color3-brand2-size3-other1
    [70] => color3-brand2-size3-other2
    [71] => color3-brand2-size3-other3
    [72] => color3-brand3-size1-other1
    [73] => color3-brand3-size1-other2
    [74] => color3-brand3-size1-other3
    [75] => color3-brand3-size2-other1
    [76] => color3-brand3-size2-other2
    [77] => color3-brand3-size2-other3
    [78] => color3-brand3-size3-other1
    [79] => color3-brand3-size3-other2
    [80] => color3-brand3-size3-other3
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this helpful?